# Criteria cutoffs for INDEX

Tags: excel

I'm not even sure how to ask this so please excuse the roundabout manner forthcoming.

I have a list of tasks and would like to use `=INDEX` to create my array. However, there are multiple different versions of the task that could show up, and I would like to have all possible avenues covered when creating (only 4 differences).

The name of the range is *TaskCode*. I want to have it so I can return the first seven numbers, the period, and then only the digits directly after the period. So in case 1, I would want 0527011.3, in case 2 I would want 0527011.01, in case 3 I would want 0527011.23, and in case 4 I'd want 0527011.3.

I initially did `=LEFT(TaskCode,10)` but that will obviously not work in case 1 or 4. Basically I need to say cut off EITHER at the second period OR the first blank.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Something like `=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)-1),A1)`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks for that. I didn't try it but found my solution. `=IFERROR(LEFT(TaskCode,(FIND(".",TaskCode,9)-1)),TaskCode)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2&".",".","|",2))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't try it but found my solution. `=IFERROR(LEFT(TaskCode,(FIND(".",TaskCode,9)-1)),TaskCode)`